# imac will not boot from installer usb drive or go into recovery mode

Tags: catalina, usb, dual-boot

I have a 2014 27" imac which keeps crashing with kernel panics, or stops half way on loading bar and restarts.
It is Running Catalina with a fusion drive setup.
I have tried recovery comm + R but get error -2002D.
I have tried safe mode but will not load just the same as a normal startup and restarts.
I tried to run apple diagnostic but this will not work and goes to recovery screen.
Pressing option will show Mac drive (Boot) a windows partition and my usb installer.
If i boot from the installer usb it does the same as a normal boot and crashes and restarts.
I pulled the fusion drive out so it has no HDD inside but when booting from the usb installer get an apple logo and that is all.
I can not get to disk utils from any of my options.
Is this a firmware issue or logicboard problem?

Comment: Have you try doing SMC Reset : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295 and NVRAM Reset : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063 ?  Then try a Internet Recovery  (cmd+alt+r at boot).

Comment: -2002D is already an Internet Recovery comms error - so it couldn't find the regular Recovery partition… but then couldn't find an internet connection. Wire up to Ethernet if you're on WiFi.

Comment: Hi,
I tried the resets but same result.
Does not detect my ethernet connection only wifi.
Tried to boot  high sierra from an external SSD but just the same result reboots and sits on apple logo.

Comment: Probably time for a repair shop then.